# Filter to display only modified content in Views

Tags: views

I created a view that displays the number of nodes modified by each user on a specific month.
I check the "modification date". The problem is that I also obtain nodes that have never been modified but have been created on that date.

In the node table, "created" and "changed" fields have the same value when the node is created. How can I only retrieve the nodes that have been modified but not created on a specific month ?

Maybe a way of doing this is to check if node.changed <> node.created, but how can I do that in views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately impossible to do it in the current UI.

There are 3 options AFAIK :

- try the module [views custom conditions](https://drupal.org/project/views_custom_conditions)
- write an [alter hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7),
- or implement a [filter handler](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_handlers/7), which is definitely going to be slightly more complicated, but probably [more fun](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/a-views-handler-the-easy-way/) :)

A repaired :) attempt to do the alter hook (with help from [another answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76651/how-to-use-hook-views-query-alter-to-modify-where-condition) on this great site) and the [add_where_expression](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default::add_where_expression/7) function :

```
function main_mm_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == 'admin_views_user') {
    $query->add_where_expression(0,'users.access < users.login');
  }
}
```

This is the view that comes with the module [admin views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views). there are 2 columns - access and login, both are dates and this seems to work :) you will want to do a dpm($query) first, to see your actual query.

Comment: I tried to alter the query to do something like node.created <> node.changed but it did nothing... About handlers, I saw the tutorial you mentionned when I was looking for a solution, but I was expecting not to deal with so much stuff only for my little problem. Well, time to get my hands dirty ! If you have an idea for a query alter, I'd like to hear about it before I try the handler.

Comment: @Grendel I added some code :) try it.

Comment: I tried with : 
`$cond = array(
  'field' => 'node.created',
  'value' => array('node.changed'),
  'operator' => '<'
);`
but the query generated is wrong, it contains `AND (node.created < 'node.changed')`. The quotes where added by views.

Comment: thanks for checking and sorry, apparentlyi was wrong :) this could be of help : https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where_expression/7 i will try to improve my code above :)

Comment: done, see code :)

Comment: and once i saw how easy it would be to do a module for this i realized there must be one ... and there is :) improving the answer one more time

Comment: I successfully used the query alter. Thorough and very helpful answers, thanks a lot ! I'll look into the module too.

Answer (score 0):

In view's `Filter criteria`:

- first filter: `Content: Post date` `Is greater than (or equal to)` `-1 month`
- second filter: `Content: Updated date` `Is less than` `-1 month`

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise. I have an exposed filter on the modification date. If I select "June 2014", I only want contents edited at least one time on June 2014. If the content hasn't beed edited since it's creation, it shouldn't be displayed. Your answer doesn't seem to adress that specific problem.