# Number as letter search and vice versa

Tags: search

I'm looking at creating a private number / license plate application and wondered what the best tools were for the search aspect of it.

I would like the search to have the ability to have the letter A show results including the number 4.  For example a search for "A4" would show 44, AA, 4A, A4. I would like the ability to be able to set the parameters eg A = 4, L = 1 and so on.

What would you recommend I use?

Comment: Do you only need to search full number plates? Or do you need results if someone types AS5 but that's only the start of a plates? It's not a particularly easy thing to do.. The easiest way would be to take advantage of contextual filters' "Allow multiple values" and pass all of the possible combinations that way.

Comment: Ideally any combinations. AS5 would also show 81G AS5 for instance.

Comment: For any combination, it goes from really complicated to really really complicated. You could try to use a views hook to alter filters. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76651/how-to-use-hook-views-query-alter-to-modify-where-condition . Or you could query the database directly from a custom form with ajax, which is what I would do. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x Either way, you're going to need to loop through each character of your search string and create an array of search terms.

Comment: If any other experienced devs have ideas, please post.

Comment: This could also be useful for Views. https://groups.drupal.org/node/82219

Comment: I'm thinking of using Solr. I've just found this which pretty much answers my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806968/search-number-plates-using-solr?rq=1

Comment: Ok, good luck with it.