# Save content with current user roles and add filter to show only content with current user role

Tags: 7, nodes

Using drupal 7,
when creating new content of the type "Document"
the current user roles must be added so I can later on show only Documents of his current role.

For example, we have the following user: this is Jake, he is a Firefighter. He creates a document about the dangers and pitfalls of being a firefighter. This is only relevant for Firefighters. So in the list of documents (view) I want Jake and all other Firefighters only to see Firefighter Documents.

So if Jake create new content of the type "document" I want to add his user roles 
and later on add a filter in the view so only Firefighters get to see Firefighter Documents

I want to have the following filter for the list Document view:

- Published = true
- Content type = Document
- User role = current user roles (Firefighter in this case)

Access must be restricted for every user based on their role.
For example, Jake the Firefighter is **not allowed** to view Policemen Documents

Comment: One possibility would be to join the user data by author id on the document. From there you can filter the documents by roles attached to the user.
You can probably alter the query with hoot_views_query_alter: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76651/how-to-use-hook-views-query-alter-to-modify-where-condition
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134941/adding-a-join-statement-in-hook-views-query-alter

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add author's role to a node directly. 
You can add user's role based **Exposed Filter** option in a view by using relationship. To do this please follow steps of below:

1. Create your view as usual (like configure view name, display type
   etc)
2. From **Fields** section add all desire fields.
3. From **Filter Criteria** choose appropriate node type.
4. Click on the **Advanced** button (indicated by an arrow on right side of the view).
5. Click on the Add button of the **Relationship** section and add `Content: Author` as a relationship.
6. Now Click on the Add button of the **Filter Criteria** section and add `User: Roles` as a filter. In this filter settings pop-up form, enable or check `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it` option then choose `Is one of` option as an operator.

Output/result:
[image]

Comment: A user is only allowed to show content of his own role. So for example, a Firefighter is only allowed to view Firefighter documents and a police officer is only allowed to view Police Documents. Therefore a Police officer can't view Firefighter Documents. I've edited my question for clarification.

And the filter must be set on the current logged in user role, they're not allowed to choose

Comment: Then you can get more help from this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/